# Is there any UCI GUI for arbitrary variants?

Tags: engines, chess-variants, uci

I have a [UCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Chess_Interface)-compatible chess engine which I modified to play a chess variant (gravity chess, where all non-pawn pieces fall towards increasing rank). However, there's no easy way to play against the modified engine in a GUI, since it assumes the engine is playing either standard chess or one of a few variants. Is there any UCI GUI which supports arbitrary variants, or one that is easy to modify to support gravity chess?

Answer (score 1):

[CECP](https://www.gnu.org/software/xboard/engine-intf.html) (xboard) goes quite far in allowing using the protocol to play chess variants, though I'm sure you can cook up something that goes beyond its limits.

[FairyFishGUI](https://github.com/fairy-stockfish/FairyFishGUI) is a minimal GUI that's used to have a simple GUI for new variants added to [Fairy Stockfish](https://github.com/ianfab/Fairy-Stockfish), a variants chess engine. It should be fairly simple to modify to support your variant. The Fairy Stockfish project in general is a good place to start looking for how to support oddball variants.